# Recursion in Prolog: Addition to variables

Tags: recursion, prolog

I don't really understand how recursion works in Prolog. Assume you have the following two functions:

```
my_length([],0).
my_length([_|T], Length) :-
    my_length(T, T_length),
    Length is T_length + 1.

my_nth0(Position, [Element|_], Element, Position).
my_nth0(Position, [_|Tail], X, CurrentPos) :-
    NextPos is CurrentPos + 1,
    my_nth0(Position, Tail, X, NextPos).
```

I understand `my_nth0`: every time you call the function recursively, you increase `NextPos` by 1. However, I don't understsand `my_length`. I'd write it like this:

```
my_length([],0).
my_length([_|T], Length) :-
    T_Length is Length + 1.,
    my_length(T, T_length).
```

That seems to follow the same style as `my_nth0`. However, the first function implementation, which seems to be correct, does exactly the opposite (it basically says `T_length is Length - 1`). Why does this work?

Comment: `my_nth0/4` is needlessly inefficient on backtracking. Compare `?- length(Es,100), time((my_nth0(0,Es,X,0),false)).` with `?- length(Es,100), time((nth0(0,Es,X),false).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually try out your version of `my_length/2` to see what happens? After you fix your syntax error (:)), you'll get a 'variable not instantiated error' if you query, `my_length([1,2,3], N).` because it will attempt to evaluate `T_Length is Length + 1` when `Length` doesn't have a value. Thus, the recursive call has to come first if you use `is/2` so that `Length` has a value from the recursive call as in the first example.

In addition, in your example, you are attempting to *increase* the variable via `T_Length is Length + 1` but your recursive base case ends up with a length of `0`. You cannot "grow" the length to `0`.

```
my_length([], 0).     % Base case is length = 0
my_length([_|T], Length) :-
    % Length is UNINSTANTIATED on my_length([1,2,3], N) query
    %  so the following 'is/2' will fail to evaluate
    T_Length is Length + 1,
    my_length(T, T_length).    % T_length > Length, but base case is 0!
```

Alternatively, if you used CLPFD and fix the order of evaluation of Length versus T_Length, you can put it in the order that you are showing:

```
my_length([], 0).
my_length([_|T], Length) :-
    % The following defines an arithmetic 'relation' between Length and T_Length
    %   and is permitted as a constraint
    Length #= T_Length + 1,
    my_length(T, T_length).
```

You could also do the length using an accumulator to get the tail recursion so that you can indeed grow the length value until it reaches the end:

```
my_length(L, N) :-
    my_length(L, 0, N).

my_length([], N, N).    % Reached the length
my_length([_|T], A, N) :-   % Here, `A` is instantiated by design
    A1 is A + 1,        % So this is/2 expression will evaluate
    my_length(T, A1, N).
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the second clause of `my_length/2` *right-to-left*!

> **If** the length of `T` is `T_length`
>
> **then** the length of `[_|T]` is `T_length+1`.